# Blue lines between (not around) images

Tags: html, image, hyperlink

I'm working on a website: http://www.allaboutwinecellars.com

And on one of the galleries (the Accesory page) there are blue lines between the pictures and I don't know why, the layout is exactly the same as the first page.

Can anyone figure out why those lines are there?

Here is the first page (the correct one): http://allaboutwinecellars.com/gallery.html

Here is the second page (the one with blue lines): http://allaboutwinecellars.com/gallery-2.html

**Edit:** I tried adding `outline:none;` to my anchor tag CSS rules and it did not fix the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is your `anchor` tags. You need to explicitly set the `text-decoration` property. The line that you're seeing is the blue underline representing a hyperlink. It looks like you already have properties defined that alter `anchor`'s behavior. Simply add to it:

```
a { 
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: none;
}
```

Comment: Going back I can't believe I was once naive enough to have to ask this question.

Answer (score 0):

```
a { text-decoration: none; }
```

should fix it

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a, img{
border:0px;
outline:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add this to your css:

```
#content p a
{
color:#000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's actually a blue underline.

Use `text-decoration: none;`.